# Disable redirect canonical

Tags: theme-development, redirect

I am trying to prevent `index.php` from redirecting to a file `index.html` which I also have in the home directory. I want `index.html` to remain there for a few days until the WordPress site is finished, being the page that visitors will see, and I'd access the new installation by adding `index.php` to the url; but WordPress redirects `index.php` to `index.html` meaning that I can only view the pages and posts and not the home page. I have tried putting `remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');`
 into the `functions.php` file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem - you have to access index.php/ not just index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.htm$ index.php [NC,R]
```

**SOURCE:**
http://css-tricks.com/377-how-to-redirect-indexhtml-to-indexphp/

Comment: thanks - see i got the answer right when you were posting